# Jquery Delay on the slidedown toggle and no slide up?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im making progress i think, I have a small pause on the second level of my menu before it slides down and i can't figure why also the is no slideup I thought this would happen with toggle here is my code in a better format i hope

First the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<script src="jquery-1.7.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="nav">
<ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Surf Boards</a>
        <ul class="subnav">
            <li ><a href="#">Long Boards</a>
                <ul class="subnav">
                    <li ><a href="#">Hard Boards</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Soft Boards</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Template 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Template 3</a></li>
        </ul></li>
    <li><a href="reviews.html">Clothing</a>
                <ul class="subnav">
                    <li><a href="#">Shorts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Shirts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Hoodies</a></li>
                </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="reviews.html">Accessories</a>
            <ul class="subnav">
                <li><a href="#">Stickers</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Board Combs</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Leg Ropes</a></li>
            </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="reviews.html">Events</a>
        <ul class="subnav">
            <li><a href="#">ASAP</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Indigenous</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">International</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="reviews.html">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Next The CSS

```
<style>
    * {
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
}
  #nav {
    width: 960px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #333333;
}

ul.nav {
    margin-left: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    list-style: none;
    overflow: visible;
}
ul.nav li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;

}
ul.nav a {
    width: 8em;
    display: block;
    padding: 5px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
}
ul.nav li a:hover {

    color: #33ff66;
}
.parent {
    background-image: url("images/arrow-select.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right center;
}.parent2 {
   background-image: url("images/arrow-select.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right center;
}
.hoverParent {
    background-image: url("images/arrow.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right center;
}
div#nav ul ul li {
text-decoration: none;
color: white;
text-align: center;
background-color: #333333;
border: 1px solid #666  ;
border-top-color: #999999;
list-style: none;
}
div#nav ul ul ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
}
div#nav ul ul {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 500;
}
div#nav ul ul {display: none;}

/*Am I Overwriting the jquery??*/
div#nav ul li:hover ul{display: block;}
div#nav ul ul,
div#nav ul li:hover ul ul,
div#nav ul ul li:hover ul ul
{display: none;}

div#nav ul li:hover ul,
div#nav ul ul li:hover ul,
div#nav ul ul ul li:hover ul
{
    display: block;
}
</style>
```

Finally the JQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#nav ul li').hover(function(){
         $('ul li', this).css("display", "none").toggle(300);
    });
 $('#nav ul ul li:has(ul)').addClass("parent");
      $('#nav ul ul li:has(ul)').hover(function(){
          $(this).addClass('hoverParent');
          $('ul li', this).css("display", "none").toggle(300);
      },function() {
          $(this).removeClass('hoverParent');
      });



});
</script>
```

Hope you guys canh help.. am i on the right track  Im brand new to jquery

Comment: Contrary to popular belief, you have not in fact written this code in jQuery--you have written it in Javascript, using the jQuery *library*, which was written in Javascript.

Comment: jsFiddle for your question: http://jsfiddle.net/efLuD/1/

Comment: plz see here cannot see any delay: http://jsfiddle.net/kbqTa/

Comment: @Tats_innit you forgot to include the jquery framework and the `toggle(300);`

Comment: Still can't get it to slide up instead of just disappearing

Comment: It's because you need to handle both the mouse in and out and do the toggle during these events.

Comment: ok so how do i get it to slide up?

Comment: ok how could i adjust my code to do so, im very new feeling my way around :-))

Comment: I understand what you mean but not sure how to implement

Answer (score 0):

See http://jsfiddle.net/efLuD/2/

Although I don't think you need to use jquery for this kind of animation. If you can live with very old browsers not getting the animation, all modern browsers, e.g. Firefox, Chrome, IE9 supports CSS transitions.